# Can you select includes and scripts depending on screen size?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know you can use CSS media queries to hide and show elements according to the screen size but is there a way to selectively remove php includes and js scripts for smaller screen sizes too?

Comment: php works on server, js works on client, you cannot remove php

Comment: with a bit of juggling, sure you can play around with a few balls to get the party going.

Comment: *Play with some balls Ralph?* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *3, at a bare minimum Sam.* - @JayBlanchard but that could get a bit weird though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php scripts can not be excluded using a media query. The reason behind this is that PHP runs on the server side, and css "runs" on the client side.

There is a solution, however, using AJAX requests. If your page loads, then measure the screen width with JS, then pass that to a PHP script, then use `if` statements (or anything else you want) to decide whether it should include a file or not.

Comment: I wanted to write some examples, but the problem is that I'm on mobile :cc

Comment: no worries, I'll use $(window).width(); and if it's more than 480 use an ajax call to load the php from an external file, should work